# Migrate [careers] to Meta Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, meta, stack-overflow-jobs

I started my quest to provide feedback for Careers by finding the proper network endpoint through my internet command line.

Googling "careers meta" provided me with a direct link to MSO [careers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/careers) as the first hit on the meta network. I thought I've struck home after reading a couple of introductory paragraphs, but was actually completely misled and thankfully had the question migrated to MSE.

Indeed, the [Careers support page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/support) and the document tail refer to MSE and not MSO.

Comment: 2 downvotes, a close, 0 feedback. Great work meta community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Careers and meta have a complicated relationship. :)

When we split off MSO from MSE a couple years ago, we wanted MSO to be for things specific to Stack Overflow the Q&A community. Because of that goal, we decided that Careers-related questions probably belonged on MSE, since it was a different product.

Given [our renewed focus on programmers and the Stack Overflow brand](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/), you could argue that those questions belong on MSO rather than MSE.

The truth of the matter is that we at the company monitor both; if you land on MSE through a link from Careers, that's fine. If you navigate to MSO because it feels more natural, that's fine, too.

We'll see them either way!

Comment: Just out of curiosity is there any consideration to trying to avoid the segmentation of Careers related information across MSE/MSO? It seems a bit arbitrary if staff will migrate  from MSO to MSE or not  - some do fairly quickly - others end up getting status-*/answered on MSO instead). Given the size of the tag and the frequency of activity - I'd had thought unless there's some reason to allow knowledge to be split across sites - maybe pick one or t'other and try to stick with it (while it's at a manageable level?)

Comment: Yeah, @JonClements we're going to try to be more consistent about how employees handle Careers questions. I know so far it's been inconsistent.